# Use Dedicated VPS as a DNS

Tags: linux, centos-5, plesk

I live in Canada, I want an american IP (Speficily? So I can watch netflix on my WDTV).

I have a dedicated virtual server in California.

How do I use my VPS (CentOS 5/64Bit, PLESK) as a DNS.

Comment: Just changing your DNS will not make it work.  You're going to need to proxy all of your traffic or use a VPN to your VPS.

Comment: I'm looking to make it work something like unblock-us. WDTV has no proxy options just DNS.

Comment: unblock-us uses some proprietary technology to return different DNS entries for certain supported sites.  This is not something you're going to be able to replicate easily.

Comment: I'm not trying to do some crazy dynamic ip emulation. I just want to use my server's IP as my IP via dns.

Comment: That's not something that DNS alone can do.

Answer (score 1):

The services you mention have two components:

1. DNS server that redirects only some domains to a tunnel/proxy.
2. Tunnel/Proxy server that makes your traffic look like it is coming from it.

The 'secret sauce' is generally how a transparent proxy server is setup for #2 and selecting which hosts to redirect in #1 so only the needed traffic goes through the tunnel/proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

1. I changed the DNS to give me acces to the US Netflix using Unblock US (208.122.23.22)
2. I logged in using the account I had already created on the UK/IRL Netflix.
3. Then I changed my DNS settings to Google (8.8.8.8) - restarted the WD TV, opened the Netflix app and this time it logged me straight into the UK/IRL Netflix storefront.

http://community.wdc.com/t5/WD-TV-Live-Streaming-Discussions/Netflix-Ireland-amp-UK-working-for-anyone/m-p/333349/highlight/true#M4183

Otherwise, set the VPS to be a proxy for your network connection.

Comment: It's possible this could work. I will have to wait until I get home. I have used the service Unblock-us but since I'm already paying for my VPS I wanted to use it instead. WDTV doesnt allow you to use a PROXY, just DNS.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the hole process by using [tunlr](http://tunlr.net/get-started/) service and it's for free. No vps, no VPN or no proxy ! All you have to do is point your DNS to there service .

How it Works :-

```
Tunlr does not provide a virtual private network (VPN). Tunlr is a DNS (domain name system)
unblocking service. We’re using sophisticated technologies (a.k.a. the Tunlr Secret Sauce ©)
to re-adress certain data envelopes, tricking the receiver into thinking the envelope 
originated from within the U.S. For these data envelopes, Tunlr is transparently creating a 
network tunnel from your location to our U.S.-based servers. Any data that’s not directly 
related to the video or music content providers which Tunlr supports is not only left 
untouched, it’s also not even routed through Tunlr. In order to use Tunlr, you will have to 
change the DNS address.
```

What You need to do :-  is use there DNS

```
The primary (preferred) DNS IP address is:

142.54.177.158

The secondary (alternate) DNS IP address is:

198.147.22.212
```

It should work on your pc and WDTV as well. No need to set your vps as DNS server. If you have privacy concern then I suggest you check out and follow [this](http://forum.hostek.com/showthread.php?462-How-to-setup-DNS-with-your-VPS) instruction.